# How do I make sure only 1 instance of a specified Sound is looping and how do I stop it from looping?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently working on a game and in the player update method, I want a footstep `Sound` to start looping when the player walks and I want it to stop looping when the player stops walking. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how I make can sure that only 1 instance of the `Sound` is looping.

For clarification: I'm talking about the `gdx.audio.Sound` class. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
//Sets the footstep sound. i.e. it changes to a grass soundfile when you walk on grass.
String footstepsFilePath = gameMap.getTileSoundFilePath(rect);
setFootsteps(Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal(footstepsFilePath)));

//velocity is the speed at which the player is going in the x or y direction.
if(velocity.y != 0 || velocity.x != 0) footsteps.loop();
if(velocity.y == 0 && velocity.x == 0) footsteps.stop();
```

Result: As soon as the player starts moving, a ton of instances of the footsteps sound start looping. When the player stops moving, all of them continue looping. The first part is for obvious reasons, but I can't figure out how I can make sure that only 1 instance is looping. But for the second part, I'm not sure why not all instances of footsteps stop looping, because this is what the documentation on `stop()` says:

> Stops playing all instances of this sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you check `if(velocity.y != 0 || velocity.x != 0)` frequently, you will indeed kick off many loops. The trick is to check "is the player moving, and were they still last time I looked?" rather than just "is the player moving".

A simple way is to set a boolean flag:

```
//Sets the footstep sound. i.e. it changes to a grass soundfile when you walk on grass.
String footstepsFilePath = gameMap.getTileSoundFilePath(rect);
setFootsteps(Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal(footstepsFilePath)));

boolean isMoving = false;

//velocity is the speed at which the player is going in the x or y direction.
if((velocity.y != 0 || velocity.x != 0) && !isMoving) {
    isMoving = true;
    footsteps.loop();
}

if((velocity.y == 0 && velocity.x == 0) && isMoving) {
    footsteps.stop();
    isMoving = false;
}
```

I am not entirely certain why `stop` does not work in your case. However, the documentation for the other two [`loop`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Sound.html#loop-float-) overloads states

> You need to stop the sound via a call to stop(long) using the returned id.

Perhaps the version of `stop` you are using doesn't work, or perhaps it waits for the current loop to finish?

Comment: That worked, thanks! Did need to move boolean isMoving = false; to the constructor of course, otherwise it would keep getting overridden. And the stop() method with the long parameter also worked.